# Why sessions data in my db differ from sessions data when i use session->all?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use sessions (i need to save sessions in mySql db) in my application on laravel.
So when i log in (use standart LoginController. It was make with php artisan as my sessions table in db) my session save in db as i need but when i use
`$value = $request->session()->all();`
in my test controller i get data i don't understand

It is in my db
[image]

it is what i get when use session()->all();
[image]

and if i want to save it (for test)
`$request->session()->put(['user_id'=>889900])` 
nothing happens

so.
What the data when i use session()->all();?
How can i save data what i need in db and when i need (i mean controllers)?

session.php 
`'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
'table' => 'sessions',`

.env 
`SESSION_CONNECTION=mysql
SESSION_DRIVER=database`

unfortunately i can't find something use in documentation to my question.
Sorry to my english and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload in your db you need to decode and unserialize it so that you can have the same result.
For example:

```php
    return Session::all();
```

and

```php
    $data = DB::table('sessions')->get();

    return unserialize(base64_decode($data[0]->payload));
```

For Those two you should have the same result.

For pushing `key` and `value`, `session(['foo' => 'bar']);` should work.

Hopefully, I have answered your question.

Comment: if i right understand in $data[0]->payload stored data in mySql but in serialize()?

Comment: @AlexeySamara, it's encode() and serialize(), so you need to decode() and unserialize() it to get it back.